# Selling multiple products & accurate stock management

Tags: magento-1.7

All of my competitors are selling the same products but in different inventory lots.  ie:

Cadbury Buttons - each
Cadbury Buttons - pack of 10
Cadbury Buttons - pack of 24
Cadbury Buttons - pack of 48

I want to do this with M2E Pro on Amazon.

What type of product type do I use to do this?  I want to have one overall product (Cadbury Buttons - each) and then have Magento accurately handle inventory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple product for the buttons where you keep your inventory. Then create different bundle products for each multiple quantity you want to sell and add the simple product to this bundled product. If you sell a bundled product the simple product inventory will be checked and updated. You can even specify the price for the bundle to gives a better price when the qty is higher.

Comment: How would you do this for configurable products? Say T-shirts where one has to choose a size. We are also looking at "packs of products" where a new product is created very similar to the original 1 T-shirt with 1 major difference: when sold/returned etc stock needs to be changed by the pack size = 6 ...